# Is there graphics.lineBitmapStyle() or alternative method on Starling

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, starling-framework

I'm drawing graphics on a Starling sprite, I face a problem on erasing lines on background.
On flex I used  `graphics.lineBitmapStyle()` where my background `Image` is the `Bitmap` source for `lineBitmapStyle()` and draw another line above it, so I erase.
Now the same problem in Starling and I don't find `lineBitmapStyle()` to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use classic Flash DisplayObject features , so you can create textures for your Starling objects on the fly! It is very simple. 
Creating your bitmap:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(YourBitmapData);
var shape:Shape = new Shape();
var g:Graphics = shape.graphics;
g.lineStyle(10);
g.lineBitmapStyle(bitmapData);
g.moveTo(0, 0);
g.lineTo(100, 100);
```

Now creating texture with it:

```
var textureData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0x0);
textureData.draw(shape);

var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmapData(textureData);
var image:Image = new Image(texture);
addChild(image);
```

`Texture` and `Image` are Starling-framework classes.

Comment: Thanks,It works but with low performance because I draw alots and each time I need to addChild(image) which slow down performance.
Is there another method.
What about lineTexture is there way to specify the portion of texture to draw like lineBitmapStyle

Comment: @HasanHouji yes it's true, if you need to do it on each enter_frame you need to find other way. may be on initialization simply duplicate and place your images in line and it will cause same effect and will not slow down performance